# executing "php -r" mysql_connect() not returning link resource

Tags: php, hyperlink, identifier, mysql-connect

I've been embedding some php in my shell scripts.  Stuff like this works:

SUBJECT_URL=`php -r "echo rawurlencode('$SUBJECT');"`

and sets my string variable SUBJECT_URL to the converted value of $SUBJECT

However,

I am trying to use this command:

link=`php -r "mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword');"`

To test my connection to the SQL database.  Unfortunately, the value for "link" is not getting set.  Therefore I can't test it for success and can't issue the:

php -r "mysql_close($link);"

to release the resource.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a wrong approach.

Comment: @jim Are you using mysql_connect because you're using an old version of php?

Comment: what version of php? you can't use mysql_connect after version 5.5

Comment: That `mysql_connect` function (deprecated) returns an object which is probably not supported in how you're trying to use it

Comment: Running PHP 5.3.3.  What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is because mysql connection dies with php.
Now if you really cannot just connect to mysql without using php from where you type, you could use something like :

```
php -r "echo @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword')? 'connected' : 'not connected';"
```

You don't need to release the connection as php will do it for you when it exits.

Comment: Thanks, I understand why I need the "echo" command in my top example, but don't understand why or how it works in (fab2s)'s example .  Sorry that my shell programming is rusty, but what is the ? 'connected" : 'not connected" part doing?  Looks like a conditional output?

Comment: that's all you can do this way, find out if a connection can be established, but not manipulate it as it dies with php wich dies right after the ';'. Why not just writing your script in php if you need php to connect ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `php -r` is almost certainly the wrong approach; if you need to use PHP you'd be better off writing the whole script in PHP instead of a mix of Shell as well.

The reasons `link=php -r "mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword');"` doesn't work is that (a) `mysql_connect` returns a resource to the database connection, which is not something that can be coerced into a string, and (b) your one-line PHP script (`mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword');` doesn't `echo` that resource anyway, i.e. it doesn't even attempt to coerce the resource into a string.

The `mysql_connect` function returns `false` on failure, so if you want your `link` variable to indicate success or failure you can assign a string to it accordingly. In a one-liner the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) is a simple way to do that, as [fab2s noted in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42496714/12559) (`echo @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword')? 'connected' : 'not connected'`). In that code the `@` (silence operator) prevents a failed connection from raising a Warning from PHP, and the use of the ternary operator conditionally returns `"connected"` if the call returned something "truthy" and `"not connected"` if it returned `false`.

As an aside, note that you really shouldn't use the old MySQL extension any longer. In fact, it's generally best to use PDO:

```
<?php
$dbConn = new \PDO(
    'mysql:dbname=my_db;host=localhost;charset=utf8',
    'user',
    'password',
    [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERR_EXCEPTION]
);
```

Comment: On PHP 5.3 you can't use short array syntax, so that last parameter for the PDO constructor would be `array (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERR_EXCEPTION)`. However, I strongly recommend you upgrade to a more recent version of PHP; 5.3 is slow and insecure.